# django : get the current locale inside a templatetag

Tags: python, django, localization, django-templates

I've an internationalized django (1.4) app.

In this app, I have a templatetag which needs to know what is the current language.

I think I could use `django.utils.translation.get_language` but it seems that inside the templatetag, it returns the default language and not the current language.

I fixed it by reading `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` from context.

But I would like to know if there is a better way to get the language in a templatetag

Answer (score 2):

There's a few [default templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#other-tags) you can use

```
{% get_current_language %}
```

or

```
{% get_current_language as FOO %}
```

e.g.

```
{% render_bar request FOO %}
```